# pandas Dataframe: Subtract a groupby mean of subset data from the full original data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to subtract [a groupby mean of subset] from the [original] dataframe:

I have a pandas DataFrame data whose index is in datetime object (monthly, say 100 years = 100yr*12mn) and 10 columns of station IDs. (i.e., 1200 row * 10 col pd.Dataframe)

1)
I would like to first take a subset of above data, e.g. top 50 years (i.e., 50yr*12mn),

```
data_sub = data_org[data_org.index.year <= top_50_year]
```

and calculate monthly mean for each month for each stations (columns). e.g.,

```
mean_sub = data_sub.groupby(data_sub.index.month).mean()
```

or

```
mean_sub = data_sub.groupby(data_sub.index.month).transform('mean')
```

which seem to do the job.

2)
**Now I want to subtract above from the [original] NOT from the [subset]**, e.g.,

```
data_org - mean_sub
```

which I do not know how to. So in summary, I would like to **calculate monthly mean from a subset of the original data (e.g., only using 50 years), and subtract that monthly mean from the original data month by month**.

It was easy to subtract if I were using the full [original] data to calculate the mean (i.e., *.transform('mean')* or *.apply(lambda x: x - x.mean())* do the job), but what should I do if the mean is calculated from a [subset] data?

Could you share your insight for this problem? Thank you in advance!

---

@mozway
The input (and also the output) shape looks like the following:

[Input shape with random values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueDFd.png)

Only the values of output are anomalies from the [subset]'s monthly mean. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the input dataframe and the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is replace non matched values to `NaN` by [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), so after [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) get same indices like original `DataFrame`, so possible subtract:

```
np.random.seed(123)
data_org = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,3)), 
                        index=pd.date_range('2000-01-01',periods=10, freq='3M'))
print (data_org)
            0  1  2
2000-01-31  2  2  6
2000-04-30  1  3  9
2000-07-31  6  1  0
2000-10-31  1  9  0
2001-01-31  0  9  3
2001-04-30  4  0  0
2001-07-31  4  1  7
2001-10-31  3  2  4
2002-01-31  7  2  4
2002-04-30  8  0  7

top_50_year = 2000
data1 = data_org.where(data_org.index.to_series().dt.year <= top_50_year)
print (data1)
              0    1    2
2000-01-31  2.0  2.0  6.0
2000-04-30  1.0  3.0  9.0
2000-07-31  6.0  1.0  0.0
2000-10-31  1.0  9.0  0.0
2001-01-31  NaN  NaN  NaN
2001-04-30  NaN  NaN  NaN
2001-07-31  NaN  NaN  NaN
2001-10-31  NaN  NaN  NaN
2002-01-31  NaN  NaN  NaN
2002-04-30  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

---

```
mean_data1 = data1.groupby(data1.index.month).transform('mean')
print (mean_data1)
              0    1    2
2000-01-31  2.0  2.0  6.0
2000-04-30  1.0  3.0  9.0
2000-07-31  6.0  1.0  0.0
2000-10-31  1.0  9.0  0.0
2001-01-31  2.0  2.0  6.0
2001-04-30  1.0  3.0  9.0
2001-07-31  6.0  1.0  0.0
2001-10-31  1.0  9.0  0.0
2002-01-31  2.0  2.0  6.0
2002-04-30  1.0  3.0  9.0
```

---

```
df = data_org - mean_data1
print (df)
              0    1    2
2000-01-31  0.0  0.0  0.0
2000-04-30  0.0  0.0  0.0
2000-07-31  0.0  0.0  0.0
2000-10-31  0.0  0.0  0.0
2001-01-31 -2.0  7.0 -3.0
2001-04-30  3.0 -3.0 -9.0
2001-07-31 -2.0  0.0  7.0
2001-10-31  2.0 -7.0  4.0
2002-01-31  5.0  0.0 -2.0
2002-04-30  7.0 -3.0 -2.0
```

Another idea with filtering:

```
np.random.seed(123)
data_org = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,3)), 
                        index=pd.date_range('2000-01-01',periods=10, freq='3M'))
print (data_org)
            0  1  2
2000-01-31  2  2  6
2000-04-30  1  3  9
2000-07-31  6  1  0
2000-10-31  1  9  0
2001-01-31  0  9  3
2001-04-30  4  0  0
2001-07-31  4  1  7
2001-10-31  3  2  4
2002-01-31  7  2  4
2002-04-30  8  0  7

top_50_year = 2000
data_sub = data_org[data_org.index.year <= top_50_year]
print (data_sub)
            0  1  2
2000-01-31  2  2  6
2000-04-30  1  3  9
2000-07-31  6  1  0
2000-10-31  1  9  0

mean_sub = data_sub.groupby(data_sub.index.month).mean()
print (mean_sub)
    0  1  2
1   2  2  6
4   1  3  9
7   6  1  0
10  1  9  0
```

Create new column `m` for months:

```
data_org['m'] = data_org.index.month
print (data_org)
            0  1  2   m
2000-01-31  2  2  6   1
2000-04-30  1  3  9   4
2000-07-31  6  1  0   7
2000-10-31  1  9  0  10
2001-01-31  0  9  3   1
2001-04-30  4  0  0   4
2001-07-31  4  1  7   7
2001-10-31  3  2  4  10
2002-01-31  7  2  4   1
2002-04-30  8  0  7   4
```

And for this solumn are merged `mean_sub` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)

```
mean_data1 = data_org[['m']].join(mean_sub, on='m')
print (mean_data1)
             m  0  1  2
2000-01-31   1  2  2  6
2000-04-30   4  1  3  9
2000-07-31   7  6  1  0
2000-10-31  10  1  9  0
2001-01-31   1  2  2  6
2001-04-30   4  1  3  9
2001-07-31   7  6  1  0
2001-10-31  10  1  9  0
2002-01-31   1  2  2  6
2002-04-30   4  1  3  9

df = data_org - mean_data1
print (df)
            0  1  2  m
2000-01-31  0  0  0  0
2000-04-30  0  0  0  0
2000-07-31  0  0  0  0
2000-10-31  0  0  0  0
2001-01-31 -2  7 -3  0
2001-04-30  3 -3 -9  0
2001-07-31 -2  0  7  0
2001-10-31  2 -7  4  0
2002-01-31  5  0 -2  0
2002-04-30  7 -3 -2  0
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @jezrael,

but the .where() invokes an error,
`ValueError: Array conditional must be same shape as self`

Also, the actual job I want to do in selecting is, not "~.index.year <= some_value" but something like "~.index.year.isin(list_of_years)"

however, selecting is a minor problem, and still struggling to subtract subset groupby mean from the original. but thanks a lot.

Comment: @WonMoo - You are right, added [`Index.to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html) for convert `DatetimeIndex` to `Series` for correct ouput. Added sample data to answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is brilliant! May not be super memory friendly, however, your solution perfectly does the job. Thank you very much again! Have a good one!

Comment: @WonMoo - Added another solution, should be more memory friendly ;)

Comment: Thank you so very much! It was my very first Q on stack overflow so it took me some time to figure out how to accept it lol. By the way, i went with your first  suggestion for my final coding (with slight modification), as it seemed more straightforward to me. However, the 2nd one also seems to be a great approach. Many thanks! May the force be with you!